# Cadastrar documentos embutidos únicos

Tags: mongodb

Quero adicionar um documento embutido, estou utilizando o `$push` do update, no schema coloquei o atributo como `index: { unique : true }`, mas não esta respeitando a regra esta cadastrando item como o mesmo nome

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
var funcionario = new Schema({
    nome : { type : String, index : { unique : true } }
});

var empresa = new Schema({
    nome : { type : String },
    funcionario : [ funcionario ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ao invés do $push, tenta usar o operador $addToSet (pelo $push assumi que o seu campo é um array). O índice único vai fazer com que você não tenha dois documentos com o mesmo valor no campo, não vai cuidar valores repetidos dentro do array.